# Using TOR bridges On Fedora (How to install obfs4proxy on Fedora)

Tags: obfsproxy, obfs4proxy, fedora

For a while I'm using Fedora Linux, I used to use Ubuntu before.

On Ubuntu simply you use `sudo apt install opfs4proxy` and then boom, just add the bridge to the `torrc` document and it works.

but I'm wondering how to install obfs4proxy On Fedora
because it seems that this package doesn't exist on Fedora.

```
sudo yum install obfs4proxy
```

And Result:

```
No package obfs4proxy available.
```

obfsproxy is not available too.

How i can add the repository or install obfs4proxy In Fedora 24?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be available/packaged for FC/RH, however...

You could use the obfs4proxy binary packaged with Tor Browser by running.

```
wget https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.0.4/tor-browser-linux64-6.0.4_en-US.tar.xz{,.asc}
gpg --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290
gpg --list-keys --fingerprint 0x4E2C6E8793298290
# Manually verify fingerprint against https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en or web of trust here
gpg --verify tor-browser-linux64-6.0.4_en-US.tar.xz.asc tor-browser-linux64-6.0.4_en-US.tar.xz
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    tar xaf tor-browser-linux64-6.0.4_en-US.tar.xz tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/obfs4proxy
    sudo cp tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/obfs4proxy /usr/local/bin/
else
    echo Signature verification failed.
fi
```

Or you could build obfs4proxy from source by installing the `golang` package then running (you may also need `git` and `mercurial`, which `go get ...` utilises):

```
export GOPATH=`mktemp -d`
go get git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfs4.git/obfs4proxy
sudo cp $GOPATH/bin/obfs4proxy /usr/local/bin/
```

To use it as a client, add the following lines to your torrc

```
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3,obfs4,scramblesuit exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy
UseBridges 1
```

Then also append your `Bridge ...` lines for each of the bridges you wish to use.

To use it as a server, add the following lines to your torrc

```
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy
ORPort 31337 # This isn't where obfs4 clients connect, but needs to be set and reachable.
BridgeRelay 1
ExtORPort auto
#ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:443 # This allows you to specify where the pluggable transport will listen, if it's not defined it will pick a random high numbered port.
#PublishServerDescriptor 0 # set this if you want to manually distribute your bridge address, otherwise it will be published to the Bridge Authority and distributed through BridgeDB
```

If you're providing an obfs4 bridge, the `Bridge ...` line for your bridge can be found at `/var/lib/tor/pt_state/obfs4_bridgeline.txt` (assuming `/var/lib/tor/` is your `DataDirectory`)